# How can I list all licenses for a single user with google's Enterprise License Manager API

Tags: google-admin-sdk

So far all the other API calls I worked with on the admin SDK seem to allow the params needed to properly filter what do/don't need.  With this one, however, it seems I need to dump all licenses and them search through the results for the one I need.  I need to keep track of the `pageToken` and make multiple calls now as I won't get all the results in the first response.

I would really like to add `userId=` to the call, but I don't see the option.  Has anyone else found a workaround?  Is there a better approach to this?

```
results = licservice.licenseAssignments().listForProduct(productId='Google-Apps', customerId='admarketplace.com', maxRecords=1000).execute()
```